# Ayuda con sentencia SQL (MySQL y PHP) Seleccionar datos de múltiples tablas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Necesito seleccionar los 8 últimos registros de una tabla (juegos), y seleccionar el número de visitas, puntuación media y número de puntuaciones.

**games | Tabla de juegos** *(Desde donde se seleccionas los últimos 8 registros):*

```
---------------------------
| name      | created_at  |
---------------------------
```

**views | Tabla de visitas** *(Se crea un registro por visita, solo hay que contar el número de registros)*

```
-----------
| game_id |
-----------
```

**ratings | Tabla de las puntuaciones** *(Hay que sacar la media de las puntuaciones y sumar número de registros)*

```
-------------------------------------
| game_id  | rate (DECIMAL [2,1]    |
-------------------------------------
```

He mostrado solo las columnas necesarias.
Dejo abajo la única solución válida a la que puedo llegar *(como se puede apreciar, funciona pero tiene el premio a la sentencia más ineficiente de todos los tiempos xD)*:

```
SELECT name FROM games ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 0, 8
```

**Y luego por cada registro** *(8 veces y encima sale separado en muchas variables)*:

```
// Por cada juego...
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE game_id = ?
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(rating) FROM ratings WHERE game_id = ?
```

Entonces, me gustaría hacer eso pero en una sola sentencia para que además de ser más eficiente, obtenga un resultado similar a:

```
$juegos [
    [name, views, avg_rate, num_rates], // 8 veces...
];
```

Comment: ¿Cómo relacionas la tabla `views` con la tabla `games`? ¿Hay un `id` en `games`?

Comment: Así es, en `games` hay un `id`, y en las otras dos hay un `game_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que habrá alguna solución menos ingenua pero esto es lo primero que se me ocurre. Primero obtener el número de visitas de cada juego:

```
SELECT   g.`id`, g.`name`, COUNT(*) AS `view_cnt`
FROM     (SELECT * FROM `games` ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 8) g
JOIN     `views` v ON v.`game_id` = g.`id`
GROUP BY g.`id`, g.`name`;

+----+----------+----------+
| id | name     | view_cnt |
+----+----------+----------+
|  5 | Juego 5  |       10 |
|  6 | Juego 6  |        6 |
|  7 | Juego 7  |       22 |
|  8 | Juego 8  |        8 |
|  9 | Juego 9  |        3 |
| 10 | Juego 10 |        6 |
| 11 | Juego 11 |        8 |
| 12 | Juego 12 |        8 |
+----+----------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

y ahora sobre esta tabla calcular el *rating* medio:

```
SELECT t1.`id`, t1.`name`, t1.`view_cnt`,
       COUNT(r.`rate`) AS `rate_cnt`, AVG(r.`rate`) AS `avg_rate`
FROM (
    SELECT   g.`id`, g.`name`, COUNT(*) AS `view_cnt`
    FROM     (SELECT * FROM `games` ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 8) g
    JOIN     `views` v ON v.`game_id` = g.`id`
    GROUP BY g.`id`, g.`name`
) t1
JOIN  `ratings` r ON r.`game_id` = t1.`id`
GROUP BY t1.`id`, t1.`name`;

+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | name     | view_cnt | rate_cnt | avg_rate |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  5 | Juego 5  |       10 |       14 |  3.30714 |
|  6 | Juego 6  |        6 |        9 |  6.30000 |
|  7 | Juego 7  |       22 |       33 |  4.96364 |
|  8 | Juego 8  |        8 |       11 |  5.51818 |
|  9 | Juego 9  |        3 |        4 |  4.35000 |
| 10 | Juego 10 |        6 |        9 |  5.83333 |
| 11 | Juego 11 |        8 |       10 |  5.57000 |
| 12 | Juego 12 |        8 |       14 |  5.55714 |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+

8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```